# Android Databinding Cannot find a setter for * that accepts parameter type *

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

Am trying to declare a variable in databinding layout it's type is array of integer but I getting an error when building the project

> Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.LinearLayout
> app:availableGradesIndexes> that accepts parameter type 'int[]'
>
> If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is
> annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.

the variable declaration in xml

```
<variable
    name="availableGradesIndexes"
    type="int[]" />

<variable
    name="subject"
    type="Subject" />
```

the binding adapter

```
@BindingAdapter("availableGradesIndexes", "subject")
fun LinearLayout.bindGradeWithMarks(availableGradesIndexes: Array<Int>) {
    //....
}
```

usage

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:subjct="@{subject}"
        app:availableGradesIndexes="@{availableGradesIndexes}"
        tools:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp" />
```

**What else I Tried**

tried to declare the type of binding adapter method to `IntArray` like `fun LinearLayout.bindGradeWithMarks(availableGradesIndexes: IntArray)`

also tried a `List<Int>` like `fun LinearLayout.bindGradeWithMarks(availableGradesIndexes: List<Int>)` and variable type `List&lt;Int&gt;`

also tried the binding variable type to be `Integer` and `Integer[]` and also `List&lt;Integer&gt;`

**so the question is how to bind a list or array of integer with binding adapter ?!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in another attribute name and I don't know why the error message didn't mention it !!

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:subjct="@{subject}" //the attribute name was messing a letter (subject)
        app:availableGradesIndexes="@{availableGradesIndexes}"
        tools:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar type of problem as mentioned in title. I was trying to change the visibility via data binding for `<include>` tag layout, like this:

```
<include
            android:id="@+id/viewNoData"
            layout="@layout/layout_no_data"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quickActionRv"
            android:visibility="@{case== Case.NoData? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}
            />
```

The solution was that I had to wrap my sublayout **layout_no_data** with

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

    </data>
Your content layout
</layout>
```

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

It is because Array<Int> in Kotlin is Integer[] in Java.
Try to use **IntArray** in Java it will be int[].

I tried your example with IntArray and it works.

```
@BindingAdapter("availableGradesIndexes")
fun LinearLayout.bindGradeWithMarks( availableGradesIndexes: IntArray ) {
}
```

Can you show your layout XML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="availableGradesIndexes"
            type="int[]" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:availableGradesIndexes="@{availableGradesIndexes}"
        tools:layout_height="match_parent" />

</layout>
```

Comment: You tried and works?, what was the variable type in xml?

Comment: As in your example type="int[]"

Comment: Except it, LinearLayout.bindGradeWithMarks should be static or be outside your activity/fragment

Comment: didn't work for me and getting the same error `Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.LinearLayout app:availableGradesIndexes> that accepts parameter type 'int[]'`

Comment: yes it's a top level function

Comment: Can you check it for int or another simple type? Just for sure that it is problem with int[]

Comment: Yes am using String[] in another layout and works good with variable type `Array<String>` in bind method

Comment: I saw you try using `type="Integer[]"` with `Array<Int>` instead of `type="int[]"`.

Have you tried clean cache? =)
Can you show your code?

Comment: Try to use String[] in this layout, it can be a problem with layout

Comment: Have you tried using String[] in this layout?

Comment: No it is not working also

Comment: In this case, we can understand that it is not a problem with int[] it is a problem with ide or layout/activity. Try to clean cache or reinstall ide. Sorry, but without your code, I can not help =(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `int[]` you can use a `List`, but this requires to import the `List` class into the layout in order to be able to use it as a `type` for the `availableGradesIndexes` variable:

```
<data>

    <import type="java.util.List" />

    <variable
        name="availableGradesIndexes"
        type="List&lt;Integer&gt;" />
</data>
```

Then you can apply that to the BindingAdapter using a `List<Int>`:

```
@BindingAdapter("availableGradesIndexes")
fun LinearLayout.bindGradeWithMarks(availableGradesIndexes: List<Int>) {
    //....
    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "bindGradeWithMarks: $availableGradesIndexes") // For testing
}
```

If you want to use the `int[]` array; no imports are required:

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="availableGradesIndexes"
        type="int[]" />

</data>
```

And the adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("availableGradesIndexes")
@JvmStatic
fun LinearLayout.bindGradeWithMarks(availableGradesIndexes: IntArray) {
    //....
    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "bindGradeWithMarks: ${availableGradesIndexes.toList()}")
}
```

**UPDATE:**

> `Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.LinearLayout app:availableGradesIndexes> that accepts parameter type 'java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>'`

This means that the `BidningAdapter` method is not recognized in the layout; so just make sure to add it in a companion object, and annotated by `@JvmStatic`:

```
class BindingAdapters {

    companion object {
        @BindingAdapter("availableGradesIndexes")
        @JvmStatic
        fun LinearLayout.bindGradeWithMarks(availableGradesIndexes: List<Int>) {
            //....
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "bindGradeWithMarks: $availableGradesIndexes")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question I tried it and got the same error

Comment: @HussienFahmy Do you get `Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.LinearLayout app:availableGradesIndexes> that accepts parameter type 'int[]'` on a `List`? This is not possible.. Please publish the error now after trying the answer. I test it out

Comment: `Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.LinearLayout app:availableGradesIndexes> that accepts parameter type 'java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>'`

Comment: @HussienFahmy Please have a look at the `UPDATE` section

Comment: but its already a top level function

Comment: Just to make sure do you have `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` plugin in gradle?

Comment: yes sir it's applied

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce this error, even tried with `IntArray` and also works for me; feel free if you'd like to post a repo demo so that I can check it out

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin Case:

1. simply put your function in companion Object like this.

   ```
   companion object {
   @BindingAdapter(" app:availableGradesIndexes", "subject")
    @JvmStatic fun LinearLayout.bindGradeWithMarks(
      availableGradesIndexes: Array<Int>) {
     //....
   }
   }
   ```
2. Make sure attributes should be same

   ```
   app:availableGradesIndexes="@{availableGradesIndexes}"
   ```

Comment: Binding methods doesn't need to be in a companion object